# Backporting float("inf") to Python 2.4 and 2.5

Tags: python, infinity, backport

I'm backporting my project from Python 2.6 to Python 2.4 and 2.5. In my project I used `float("inf")`, and now I find it is unavailable on Python 2.5. Is there a backport of it?

Comment: The 1e100000 trick fails randomly on Windows XP. It sometimes becomes just 1.0. So it is out of the question. There needs to be a class for Infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a backport, tested on Python 2.5+, can probably be easily made to work on Python 2.4:

https://github.com/cool-RR/GarlicSim/blob/master/garlicsim/garlicsim/general_misc/infinity.py

Answer (score 5):

Spelling it either the long way or the short way works fine for me:

```
$ python2.4 -c "print float('inf')+200"
inf
$ python2.5 -c "print float('inf')+200"
inf
$ python2.5 -c "print float('infinity')+200"
inf
$ python2.4 -c "print float('infinity')+200"
inf
```

The `-c` flag means "execute the following arguments as a Python command."

[PEP754](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/) (which was rejected) does mention your issue about special IEEE-754 values.  It suggests using something like `1e300000` to generate a floating point overflow and create `inf`, but it does note that this is ugly and not guaranteed to be portable.

Comment: I don't know what that `-c` flag is, but in Python 2.4 on Windows XP there seems to be no `float('inf')`, nor `float('infinity')`. It raises: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): inf`

Comment: Python float uses hardware floats, so behavior might depend on the platform. For changes, see "Many floating-point features were added." http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html

Comment: works for me on linux python 2.4.3 and osx python 2.5.6; either win32 platform doesn't follow IEEE semantics, or you have a very old python build.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to fake it up by giving Python a sufficiently large floating point constant instead. For instance:

```
>>> 1e100000
inf
>>> float('inf') == 1e1000000
True
>>> float('inf') == 2e1000000
True
```

Answer (score 1):

The [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module is available since Python 2.4 and supports positive or negative infinite decimals. It does not always behave like a float (eg. adding a decimal and a float is not supported) but does the right thing for comparison, which was good enough for me.

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('Infinity') > 1e300
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing NumPy for a few lines:

```
import numpy as np

inf = float(np.inf)
```

Here, `inf` is a [regular python `float`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5/lib/typesnumeric.html), so you don't need to bother with NumPy any further.